# WebStorm compatibility with exporting of classes

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I know that the ES6 [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)/[import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax is not part of Node.JS yet, so when I write a class in Node.JS, it usually goes something like this:

```
class Foo {
    ...
}

module.exports = Foo;
```

However, I frequently see a slightly more compact version of this:

```
module.exports = class Foo { ... }
```

When I write this code in WebStorm it will however complain "expression expected" (it doesn't like the `class` keyword in an assignment). The file seems to work fine when run with Node (~6.10) though.

Is there a compatibility setting in WebStorm to allow this? The only option I found was an inspection for warning about non-ES6 draft features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebStorm has issues resolving members of classes exported this way (see [WEB-28158](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28158)), but the syntax itself is correctly accepted (WebStorm 2017.3.2):

[image]

What IDE version do you use? Did you set **JavaScript Language Version** to **ECMAScript 6** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**?
If this doesn't help, try invalidating caches

Comment: Yeah, JS Language Version is ECMAScript 6, but I just realized my WebStorm version is old (11!). That probably explains it.